# B2C Login is showing me an error page after entering credentials. When clicked on Sign in button, it's logging me in without asking for creds

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My application is a learning platform which lets users to upskill themselves in basic areas of computers specifically for South East Asian nations.

I am using **Azure AD B2C** for user management and using **Identity Experience Framework (Custom policies)**.

Anyone can register at **https://skillourfuture.org/register**. Upon registration, the user will get an **email with the password** and simultaneously the user account gets created in both my application & B2C Tenant.

When you login to this application using the [B2C Sign in Page](https://skillourfuture.b2clogin.com/skillourfuture.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin_only_signin_v3/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=8ffcd385-7640-4830-8d41-2b990716e0a2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.skillourfuture.org%2Fsignin-b2c&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%208ffcd385-7640-4830-8d41-2b990716e0a2%20offline_access&code_challenge=TFyMd_eNx0UYIzoFod7ivb0km6VJdmt66szC3Uwpoto&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638474960767205458.MTIyYmYyMzUtMTMxOS00MGMyLThjNGQtN2M4NmNlZTk1MDhiYTM3NGExMDktMDczMC00M2ExLTgyNTgtNjhkN2Q5YzA4MDMx&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.3.0.0&state=CfDJ8Napqmltq1dCqCa23z7w3M74bLIYHpMoQQ6wg5kH9Vq7mTG3gIaPQeZqwjT3tFOaPWshPjmxTqGiZNqMnrT3uJaHhDjNzIq3lBW1Yma1oEjQrt_-SQx0r7e-mfZgPC-riYjNZeWPcp9AiESexIgoOcpRG2vqVWASA3gorr7vZs3VXL2WYQwC3ypSIpXNsDB2wcpeVAFnUKfyYV6UtEKWsX4Nj1u4NuvWIe24v8APywWYSVdIGwWguB-WoF_EOcIxCLneWN910fL2axdorehfgl8Qq28v3C4Rw3Gg6JXMHs2xQVkXK1Olhp858jAqSdyGyGvt3N6kjRWcwvtZaqY9B78m496Lv1vqb7LPKll42d_0bdAETl5wsopRZLrwQTe8Y35Q6y-tl9Ftlc359izoZvyN-OyiJYpwMNv1iboQBh041OXY0DG85US3M3mKHbgBFor4YH2RbFznq7TnN4UlpHo&x-client-SKU=ID_NET6_0&x-client-ver=6.21.0.0), I am getting an error page of Microsoft with the URL `https://learn.skillourfuture.org/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error`
When you click on the `Home` button on the error page, you will be redirected to our Homepage which is **https://learn.skillourfuture.org**. When you click on `Sign in` button on top right corner, you will directly login to the application without entering the credentials.

I want to get rid of the error when user logs in for the first time. I've logged multiple tickets with MS B2C team, but of no use.

The reason we want to use the B2C Sign in page URL is that we have implemented various languages and we will send the Sign in pages & content according to the users region.

Any possible solutions or work-around is appreciated

[image: Microsoft Error Page mentioned above]

PS: When you enter the credentials, they are getting stored in the cache and when you click on Sign in button of of my homepage, it is taking the cached creds and letting you in.

Comment: Have you used ApplicationInsights to log the error?